# Problems on OSX 10.8.3 System Console , can you help me?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, samba, console

I would like to know what the following console message means:

```
24.05.13 09:26:00,251 com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.samba.nmbd[3502]) Exited with code: 1
24.05.13 09:26:00,251 com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.samba.nmbd) Throttling respawn: Will start in 9 seconds
24.05.13 09:26:07,870 com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.daemon[3498]) Exited: Killed: 9
24.05.13 09:26:07,000 kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3498 [cfprefsd]
24.05.13 09:26:08,635 com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.sleepservicesd[3495]) Exited: Killed: 9
24.05.13 09:26:08,000 kernel[0]: memorystatus_thread: idle exiting pid 3495 [SleepServicesD]
24.05.13 09:26:09,310 com.apple.launchd[1]: (org.samba.nmbd[3504]) Exited with code: 1
```

Comment: Samba is used to connect to Window network shares.  Do you have one connected?  If so, then it appears that the daemon is having errors and is killing itself.  That may prompt some researching into where your samba daemon is installed and where it can be configured.